# Eigenvalues of non-negative block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector, block-matrices

$B$ is a non-negative irreducible block matrix as follows:

$$B=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
0 &B_{12}&B_{13}\\
\hline
B_{21}& 0& B_{23}\\
\hline
B_{31}& B_{32}&0
\end{array}
\right].$$

Is there any relation between the maximum positive eigenvalue of $B$ and the maximum positive eigenvalue of the following matrix?

$$M=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
B_{21}B_{12}& B_{21}B_{13}+B_{23}\\
\hline
B_{31}B_{12}+B_{32}B_{21}B_{12}&B_{31}B_{13}+B_{32}B_{21}B_{13}+B_{32}B_{23}
\end{array}
\right]$$

Comment: Are you maybe in the special case in which the Perron eigenvalue of $B$ is $1$? Because $M$ is obtained from $B$ by *censoring* the first block of states, in the language of Markov chains, i.e., $I-M$ is a Schur complement of $I-B$; in particular, if $B$ is stochastic then $M$ is, too, and the Perron eigenvector of $M$ is given by chopping off the last first block of that of $B$.

Comment: In fact, the maximum eigenvalue of $B$ is positive and greater than 1. Also $M$ is coming from the following multiplication:$B_3B_2B_1 in which $\\  $
B_1=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
0 &B_{12}&B_{13}\\
\hline
0& I& 0\\
\hline
0& 0&I
\end{array}
\right]$ \ $
B_2=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
I &0&0\\
\hline
B_{21}& 0& B_{23}\\
\hline
0& 0&I
\end{array}
\right]$ \ $
B_3=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
I &0&0\\
\hline
0& I& 0\\
\hline
B_{31}& B_{32}&0
\end{array}
\right]$

Comment: What motivated this question?